User-Guidance does not show on [visa] tag
For the visa tag, which gets commonly misused, I noticed the user-guidance is not showing on the tag when you mouse over it, the guidance does show when you are typing in the Tags field. The tag does not have a wiki, just user-guidance, that might be part of why it behaves this way.
Doesnt show here:

Does show here:



It doesn't have a tag wiki, so it doesn't show anything thanks to this incredibly well thought-out experiment.

Ah yep that seems to line up with what I was seeing

Nice tag name, by the way. Not ambiguous at all.
